# Prove that there is a matrix $B$ so that $\det(M + tB) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $M$ denote an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in a field $\mathbb{F}$. Prove that there is a $n\times n$ matrix $B$ with entries in $\mathbb{F}$ so that $\det(M + tB)\neq 0$ for every non-zero $t\in\mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we note that we can take $B = I$ for the case that $M = 0$ and $B = 0$ in the case that $\det(B) \neq 0$.

For the remaining cases: with a rank-decomposition, we can find invertible matrices $P,Q$ such that
$$
M = P\pmatrix{I_r&0\\0&0_{(n-r)\times (n-r)}}Q.
$$
If we take
$$
B = P \pmatrix{0_{r \times r} & 0\\0 & I_{n-r}} Q,
$$
then we find that
$$
M + tB = P \pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0 & t I_{n-r}} Q,
$$
and we see that for all non-zero $t$ we have
$$
\det(M + tB) = \det(P)\det(Q) t^{n-r} \neq 0.
$$